# Running a method before a class load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class User in which i want to do conditional validation like such:

```
if $organization.first_name_last_name
   validates :name_first, presence: true,
                  length:     { maximum: 50 },
                  :if => :local_authentication?
   validates :name_last, presence: true,
                  length:     { maximum: 50 },
                  :if => :local_authentication?
```

However this global organisation variable is an object containing specific settings for a subdomain and is initialized in the before_filter of the application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :load_organization
   ...
   def load_organization
      $organization = Organization.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain).settings
   end
```

My question is how to make the load_organization run before the User class is loaded so that the organization variable is correctly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, this can work, because the User class is not reloaded between requests, at least not in production.

You are already using the `:if` parameter for the validation. You can use this for the settings, as well:

```
validates :names_first, presence: true,
                        if: -> {
                          $organization.first_name_last_name &&
                          local_authentication?
                        }
```

BTW: Using a global variable is generally a sign for bad software design. Doesn't the user you are trying to create/update which organization it belongs to and you can access the settings via the relation getter?

P.S.: You are mixing hash syntaxes, as well. You should either use `:foo => :bar` or `foo: :bar`, but not both at the same time. Actually I'm surprised this works at all ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solved it.


I am using the apartment gem (https://github.com/influitive/apartment) which allows each request to be processed by a different database dependent on the subdomain. In a first attempt to enable multi tenancy i've created a seperate organization object for each instance to hold the configuration parameters (dependant on the needs of the client). This is merely a temporary solution